# I'm but a speck of fairy dust

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A simple riddle of mine, focused towards meter and rhyme.

> I'm but a speck of fairy dust
>   A glitt'ring jew'l, but only just
>   So small I scarcely can be seen
>   A trinity in me convenes
>
> And yet without me you can't see
>   Fine art and words are made of me
>   I'm resolute; through me you can
>   View realms beyond the mortal ken
>
> I shrink along with passing years
>   My number grows, I gain more peers
>   But treat me well 'tis very true
>   I sleep and live and die like you

Please include explanations for as many lines as possible in your answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are:

> A pixel

--

I'm but a speck of fairy dust / A glitt'ring jew'l, but only just

> Pixels are small and bright

So small I scarcely can be seen / A trinity in me convenes

> RGB

And yet without me you can't see

> You can't see content without them. Assuming specific to the context of its realm.

Fine art and words are made of me

> Again, assuming the context of its realm.

I'm resolute; through me you can / View realms beyond the mortal ken

> Pretty obvious, via the internet, games, etc.

I shrink along with passing years / My number grows, I gain more peers

> DPI increases as computers get more advanced.

But treat me well 'tis very true / I sleep and live and die like you

> "Sleep" possibly referring to monitor state, and pixels can die.

Comment: I think you got it :)

Comment: Also "fairy dust" ~ "pixie dust" ~ "pixel" and "I'm resolute" ~ "resolution"

Comment: Nice work.  Also, "jewel" > liquid crystal display

Comment: Tangential but relevant: "I shrink along with passing years": We're at 577 ppi (Galaxy S5 LTE-A) and still going.

Comment: "I shrink along with passing years": With the [Xperia Z5 Premium](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/phones/xperia-z5-premium/), we're now at **806 ppi**. 3840x2160 pixels on a 5.5-inch display. Absolutely insane.

Answer (score 12):

You are a(n):

> Atom

I'm but a speck of fairy dust

> Atoms are star-dust.

A glitt'ring jew'l, but only just

> Atoms are beautiful, why not.

So small I scarcely can be seen

> Atoms are tiny.

A trinity in me convenes

> Protons, electrons and neutrons.

And yet without me you can't see

> Atoms are all there is to comprise the so-called physical world we operate in.

Fine art and words are made of me

> Everything is comprised of atoms.

I'm resolute; through me you can
View realms beyond the mortal ken

> A reference to quantum mechanics?

I shrink along with passing years

> Atomic decay

My number grows, I gain more peers.

> Atoms are born with death of stars and expansion of the universe. Could also refer to atomic numbers increasing?

But treat me well 'tis very true
I sleep and live and die like you

> Atoms actually die.

Comment: Re the last spoiler ... umm, wat?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Technically, given an infinite time horizon, all atoms will eventually decay into fermions, then radiative subatoms.

Comment: [Something about the death of atoms](http://education.jlab.org/qa/radelement_03.html)

Comment: Second last spoiler: is the number of atoms really growing?  Nuclear fusion results in fewer, but larger atoms.

Comment: @McMagister Honestly, I don't know enough about atoms to come up with a *stellar* explanation for this

Comment: @cop It's a very good answer.  My intended answer fits the clues better IMO, but it is a similar line of thought to your answer.

Comment: @McMagister Oh well. Good really. Let's not let the fun be over so soon :)

Comment: $(+1)$ *"Atoms are beautiful, why not?"*

Answer (score 5):

> A water molecule.

I'm but a speck of fairy dust

> Water molecules are specks.

A glitt'ring jew'l, but only just

> Water and ice both glitter

So small I scarcely can be seen

> It is hard to see water molecules.

A trinity in me convenes

> Two hydrogens and one oxygen.

And yet without me you can't see

> Because there would be no humours in your eye, and life can't exist without water.

Fine art and words are made of me

> watercolors, etc.

I'm resolute; through me you can
View realms beyond the mortal ken

> Detecting water in remote galaxies, etc.

I shrink along with passing years

> Because of the expansion of the universe, you could think of everything else shrinking by comparison.

My number grows, I gain more peers

> It's raining and / or more water is made in nebulae in outer space.

But treat me well 'tis very true

> because water is good for you.

I sleep and live and die like you

> because you're 90% water.

Answer (score 1):

There have been other answers along these lines (and frankly I like CAVX's better), but the first thing that came to mind for me is:

> A carbon atom

I'm but a speck of fairy dust

> Like graphite

A glitt'ring jew'l, but only just

> Like diamond

So small I scarcely can be seen

> because atom

A trinity in me convenes

> electron, proton, neutron

And yet without me you can't see

> Your retinas are made mostly of carbon

Fine art and words are made of me

> Graphite, charcoal, most paints, all organic building materials...

I'm resolute; through me you can

> Diamond and graphene are transparent

View realms beyond the mortal ken

> and diamonds are the result of ancient geological processes

I shrink along with passing years

> nuclear weak force

My number grows, I gain more peers

> stellar fusion

But treat me well 'tis very true

> Diamonds are incredibly hard, but also brittle

I sleep and live and die like you

> We are made primarily of carbon, and carbon has a (very long) half-life too